# Bullet in List how do i remove it

Tags: css, list

Hello i like to know how can i override this using css, i have try content: "." in my class but is not working.

```
.postcontent ul > li::before, .post ul > li::before, .textblock ul > li::before {
content: url('../images/postbullets.png');
```

thanks for any help

Comment: i have all ready try use list-style-type: none; before css get to this class, but the bullet keep show, thanks for you answers

Comment: i have found a solution for the override:

    #mydiv ul > li::before { content: none; }

Answer (score 2):

This will remove bullets from your list and replace it with your image:

```
.postcontent ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: url('../images/postbullets.png');
}
```

Comment: what i need is to override the class so i can remove the bullet, i cant change that class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
li {list-style-type: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you remove the bullets in a list?  I have a feeling I'm misreading the question...

CSS

```
list-style-type: none;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: what i need is to override the class so i can remove the bullet, i cant change that class.

Comment: Look into Specificity and Inheritance to answer your question then:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/